# Activity cannot be cast to Application

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, dagger, android-mvvm

I have weather app , which display weather in your own location and also shows date.

To show UI I use Fragment, and FragmentContainer.

Literrally , I don't really understand how to bind rest api request with location permission  and show it in View.

All permissions and Application Class are already written in Manifest.

[image]

```
import android.app.Application
import di.AppComponent
import di.DaggerAppComponent

class WeatherApp:Application() {
 lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .context(app = this)
            .build()
    }
}
```

---

```
@GET("v1/forecast?latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41&current_weather=true")
suspend fun getCurrentWeather(@Query("latitude")lat:Double,@Query("longitude")lon:Double)
:Response<WeatherCurrentResponse>
```

---

```
@Component(modules = [NetworkModule::class,DomainModule::class])
interface AppComponent{
    fun viewmodelfac():WeatherViewmodelFactory
    fun viewmodel():WeatherViewModel


    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{
        fun build():AppComponent
        @BindsInstance
        fun context(app:Application):Builder
    }
}
```

---

```
@Module
interface  DomainModule {

@Binds
 fun bindrepository(currentRepositoryImpl: CurrentRepositoryImpl):CurrentRepository

    @Binds
    fun bindLocation(trackLocationImpl: TrackLocationImpl):TrackLocation

}
```

---

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {
@Provides
fun provideapi():ServiceAPI{
   return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.open-meteo.com/")
       .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(ServiceAPI::class.java)
}
    @Provides
    fun provideflocationprovider(app: Application): FusedLocationProviderClient {
        return LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(app)
    }
}
```

---

```
interface CurrentRepository {
suspend fun getCurrentWeather(lat:Double,lon:Double):Response<WeatherCurrentResponse>
}

class CurrentRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(private val api: ServiceAPI) : CurrentRepository{
    override suspend fun getCurrentWeather(
        lat: Double,
        lon: Double
    ): Response<WeatherCurrentResponse> =
        api.getCurrentWeather(lat, lon)
}
```

---

```
interface TrackLocation {
    suspend fun getCurrentlocation():Location?
}

class TrackLocationImpl@Inject constructor(private val application: Application,
private val fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
                                           ) : TrackLocation{
    override suspend fun getCurrentlocation(): Location? {
 val hasPermissionCoarse  = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
     application,
     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
 ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
 val hasPermFine = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
     application,
     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
 ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
 val locationManager = application.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        val isGPSenabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
if(!hasPermissionCoarse || !hasPermFine || !isGPSenabled){
return null
}
  return suspendCancellableCoroutine {
      i->
fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.apply {
    if(isComplete){
        if(isSuccessful){i.resume(result)} else{
            i.resume(null)
        }
        return@suspendCancellableCoroutine
    }
    addOnSuccessListener {
        i.resume(it)
    }
    addOnFailureListener{
        i.resume(null)
    }
    addOnCanceledListener {
        i.cancel()
    }
}
  }
    }
}
```

---

```
class WeatherViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: CurrentRepository,
                                           private val trackLocation: TrackLocation):ViewModel() {
private val _weatherstate = MutableLiveData<Response<WeatherCurrentResponse>>()
      val weatherstate:LiveData<Response<WeatherCurrentResponse>>
  get() = _weatherstate


    fun initweatherdata() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
           trackLocation.getCurrentlocation()?.let { 
               location -> _weatherstate.value  =
               repository.getCurrentWeather(lat = location.latitude, lon = location.longitude)
           }
        }
    }

}
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class WeatherViewmodelFactory@Inject constructor(private val repository: CurrentRepository,
                                                 private val location: TrackLocation
):ViewModelProvider.Factory{

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
      require(WeatherViewModel::class == modelClass)
        return WeatherViewModel(repository = repository, trackLocation = location) as T
    }
}
```

---

```
class ListWeatherFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var binding:FragmentListWeatherBinding
private val viewModel by viewModels<WeatherViewModel>{
getAppComponent().viewmodelfac() // error
}


 private fun Fragment.getAppComponent() : AppComponent = (requireContext() as WeatherApp)
      .appComponent // error here


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentListWeatherBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return binding.root
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.initweatherdata() // error
        viewModel.weatherstate.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner
        ) {
                weatherdisplaying ->
            binding.tempcurrent.text =
                weatherdisplaying.body()?.weathercurrent?.temp.toString()
            binding.timecurrent.text = weatherdisplaying.body()?.weathercurrent?.time?.
            format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd"))
 val location = weatherdisplaying.body()?.lat?.compareTo(weatherdisplaying.body()!!.lon)
                binding.city.text = location.toString()
 // error here
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: For future questions you probably should tag [tag:android] and [tag:kotlin] rather than the super specific `android-livedata`, `android-viewmodel`, and `android-mvvm` that probably hardly anybody is following. Then a lot more people will see the question. Also consider eliminating all the completely unrelated code. The only thing relevant to your question here was the code in your Fragment where the error occurs. Most people will just click past your question if they see walls of code in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Activity or a Context is not an Application, so you can't cast it to one. Replace

```
(requireContext() as WeatherApp)
```

with

```
(requireActivity().application as WeatherApp)
```